# SQL server - Select all items with a date on the previous month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I have a table in my SQL Server database called "**items**" which has a column called "**dateFinished**".

I have a script that will run on the 1st day of each month which needs to select all items that finished in the previous month.

So, for example, on the 1st February it will need to select all items where the dateFinished is greater than or equal to 00:00 on the 1st of January and less than 00:00 on 1st February.

it also needs to work across new years (e.g. DEC - JAN).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could get a day of the previous month with `dateadd(m,-1,getdate())`.  Then, filter on the year and month of that date in a `where` clause, like:

```
select *
from items
where datepart(yy,dateFinished) = datepart(yy,dateadd(m,-1,getdate()))
and datepart(m,dateFinished) = datepart(m,dateadd(m,-1,getdate()))
```

This should work across years, and also if the query is run on a later day than the first of the month.

Answer (score 8):

```
Select * 
  from items 
 where datefinished >= dateadd(m, datediff(m, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0) 
   AND datefinished < dateadd(m, datediff(m, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

Comment: @gbn: Interesting, but I don't think indexes can help with a range filter

Comment: You will usually get an index seek in the plan on that sort of query, in my experience...

Comment: @Andomar: with SELECT *, probably not. But an index on datefinished INLCUDE output clause = good chance

Comment: Andomar wrote "I don't think indexes can help with a range filter."  GBN wrote "With SELECT *, probably not."  And I write "A Developer must not guess. A Developer must KNOW!" ;-)  Setup a test and see that you do actually get an INDEX SEEK.  Yes, I agree that you'll get a "key lookup" with SELECT * but there's nothing about SELECT * that will prevent you from getting an INDEX SEEK.  And, yes, Andomar, it does help on a range filter. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Simple just use what I just used: `DATEDIFF(mm,dateFinished,GETDATE()) = 1`

```
SELECT * 
FROM items 
WHERE DATEDIFF(mm,dateFinished,GETDATE()) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start by checking out the DATEADD function
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx